# How are backslashs interpreted outside quotation?

Tags: bash, escaping, echo, double-quotes, backslash

I'd expect `echo -E \n` and `echo -E "\n"` to be equivalents. However `echo -E \n` prints `n` (backslash is not printed) whereas `echo -E "\n"` prints `\n` (backslash is printed). Apparently backslashs are interpreted differently not only in single and double quotes, but also in double quotes and outside of quotes. How are backslashs interpreted outside of quotes?

Comment: Double quotes themselves are a shortcut for escaping characters. `"n"` and `\n'` are the same string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outside of quotes, unescaped backslashes are always deleted. They are only used to disable the special meaning of other symbols.

Inside double quotes, backslashes are kept, except when escaping one of `$`, `` ` ``, `"`, `\`, or marking a line continuation.

From [POSIX Shell Command Language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html), emphasis mine:

> #### 2.2.1 Escape Character (Backslash)
>
> A <backslash> that is not quoted shall preserve the literal value of the following character, with the exception of a <newline>. If a <newline> follows the <backslash>, the shell shall interpret this as line continuation. The <backslash> and <newline> shall be removed before splitting the input into tokens. [....]

> #### 2.2.3 Double-Quotes
>
> Enclosing characters in double-quotes ( "" ) shall preserve the literal value of all characters within the double-quotes, with the exception of the characters backquote, <dollar-sign>, and <backslash>, as follows:
>
> [...]
>
> \
> The <backslash> shall retain its special meaning as an escape character (see Escape Character (Backslash)) **only when followed by one of the following characters** when considered special:
>
> `$`   `` ` ``   `"`   `\`   <newline>

Answer (score 3):

Backslashes are *always* removed, unless they're themselves escaped (with another backslash) or inside single- or double-quotes. From the [POSIX standard for shell syntax, section 2.2.1 "Escape Character (Backslash)"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_01):

> A <backslash> that is not quoted shall preserve the literal value of the following character, with the exception of a <newline>. If a <newline> follows the <backslash>, the shell shall interpret this as line continuation. The <backslash> and <newline> shall be removed before splitting the input into tokens. Since the escaped <newline> is removed entirely from the input and is not replaced by any white space, it cannot serve as a token separator.

...so outside of quotes, the shell interprets `\n` as a literal `n`.

Inside double-quotes, on the other hand ([section 2.2.3 "Double-Quotes"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_03)):

> \
> The <backslash> shall retain its special meaning as an escape character (see Escape Character (Backslash)) only when followed by one of the following characters when considered special:
> `` $   `   "   \   <newline> ``

...since in `"\n"`, the backslash is *not* followed by one of those characters, it doesn't retain its special meaning and is just passed through as a literal backslash.

BTW, just to add confusion, some versions of `echo` will do their own backslash-interpretation (on any that make it past the shell's parsing process), using yet another set of rules. In some versions, `-E` disables this... but some just print "-E" as part of their output. If you want predictability, use `printf` instead:

```
printf '%s\n' \n      # Prints just 'n'
printf '%s\n' "\n"    # Prints '\n'
```